# PHP in a javascript function name

Tags: php, javascript, function, onclick

This works just like it is supposed too:

```
<script>
function test() {alert("add to cart was triggered!");}
</script>

<img src="images/add-to-cart.png" width="143" height="45" onclick="test()">
```

However: This does not - (PHP generates the code correctly, but it will not trigger the javascript function when served to the browser)

```
<script>
function <?=$prodadd?>() { alert("add to cart was triggered!");}
</script>
<img src="images/add-to-cart.png" width="143" height="45" onclick="<?=$prodadd?>()">
```

When I look at the source code generated by the hard coded version and then the PHP generated version they are identical and look like this:

```
<script>
function 1prodadd()
{alert("add to cart was triggered!");}
</script>
<img src="images/add-to-cart.png" width="143" height="45" onclick="1prodadd()">
```

Why would a function name generated by PHP no longer operate as a function? Since I see no difference in the source code it don't see whats being encoded differently between what I code directly vs what I have PHP generate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to generate function names with PHP, you are doing it wrong. Can you explain why you think this is necessary?

Comment: @minitech Looping through a series of items in the database, a unique form is generated for each item. a matching function is generated as well. So that the onclick will eventually trigger `document.<?$prodadd?>.submit();` and send that unique form to the PHP handling the POST data  - It's just the way the shopping cart was designed so I'm stuck trying to work it this way. (Since Script can't trigger a PHP function without using AJAX, which I know absolutely zero about implimenting)

Comment: You’re not really stuck implementing it that way. Why not give each form a class, each image a class, and set the same click handler on every image that submits its parent form?

Comment: @minitech I'm only a few weeks into PHP, so the only class reference I know is CSS. Now assuming that's NOT what you mean, could you show me an example of what your referring to?

Comment: I am actually referring to CSS classes. Do you know JavaScript well?

Comment: @minitech fairly well, I use it as needed. This is not a full fledged HTML document, it's just a template that the PHP brings in and duplicates for each item found in the database. So since the template is identically duplicated each time, PHP was the only way I saw to give it a unique identifier during each WHILE LOOP. - if you can show me how you would do it differently with CSS/Javascript i'll look at that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31904/discussion-between-swodahs-and-minitech)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JavaScript function name must not start with a number.

To wit [from the site](http://www.functionx.com/javascript/Lesson05.htm):

The name of the function:

- **Must start with a letter or an underscore**
- Can contain letters, digits, and underscores in any combination
- Cannot contain space
- Cannot contain special characters

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. JS function will not start with numeric. Even any language will not accept this.

Comment: It can also start with a `$` sign. “Special characters” is a bit vague there. Why not link to an actually accurate reference?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to prefix your script generated function names with a dollar sign or underscore; these characters may be used anywhere inside an identifier (including the start).

The older ECMAScript definition stated that they were reserved for machine generated variable names, but that statement has been weakened in 5.1:

> This standard specifies specific character additions: The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in an IdentifierName.

[*ECMAScript 262-5.1 section 7.6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)

```
<script>
function $<?= $prodadd ?>() { alert("add to cart was triggered!");}
</script>

<img src="images/add-to-cart.png" width="143" height="45" onclick="$<?=$prodadd?>()">
```

This makes sure the variable always starts with a valid character and you can even use variables that start with numbers, like in your case, e.g. `$0` is a valid variable.

Comment: @minitech Done. Apparently they've changed their wording since 3.0 ;-)

Comment: @Jack I did change the code to generate the script name properly it has gone from: `<?php $prodadd = ++$fnme . "prodadd"; ?>' to '<?php $prodadd = "prodadd" . ++$fnme; ?> - however, the source code looks correct (function name is now prodadd1() ) but still will not trigger from the images onclick event

Answer (score -1):

Javascript function name has to start with a letter similar to a javascript variable. Please look [reference](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3652976/Writing-Your-Own-JavaScript-Functions.htm)

> The rules for naming a function are similar to those for naming a
>   variable. The first character must be a letter; the rest of the
>   characters can include letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores. No
>   other characters, including spaces, are allowed. Like variables,
>   function names are case sensitive

Comment: [Same thing applies.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160098/php-in-a-javascript-function-name/17160236?noredirect=1#comment24842671_17160109) Not a good reference. The rest of the characters: a) cannot include dashes… not sure where that comes from b) can include dollar signs. The first character can also be an underscore or a dollar sign.